# AngularJS SPA and RestfulAPI Server Security

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cookies, ssl

**Quick background:**

Full Javascript SPA AngularJS client that talks to a REstful API server. I am trying to work out the best authentication for the API Server. The client will have roles and I am not concerned if the user can see areas of the client they aren't allowed because the server should be air tight.

**Authentication flow:**

- User Posts Username and Password to let's say /api/authenticate
- If a user the server generates api token ( sha hash of fields or md5) and some other meta data determining roles to pass back in 1) post reply.
- The token is stored in a session cookie (no exp, http only, ssl)
- Each request after authentication takes the token in the cookie and verifies this is the user.
- SSL user on server.

**Questions:**

- Is this the best way to secure the server?
- Do I need to worry about replay attacks w/ SSL? If so best way to manage this?
- I tried to think of a way to do HMAC security with AngularJS but I can't store a private key on a javascript client.
- I initially went the http authentication method but sending the username and password each request seems odd.

Any suggestions or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently working on a similar situation using angularjs+node as a REST API, authenticating with HMAC.

I'm in the middle of working on this though, so my tune may change at any point. Here's what I have though. Anyone willing to poke holes in this, i welcome that as well:

1. User authenticates, username and password over https
2. Server (in my case node.js+express) sends back a temporary universal private key to authenticated users. This key is what the user will use to sign HMACs client side and is stored in LocalStorage on the browser, not a cookie (since we don't want it going back and forth on each request).

   - The key is stored in nodejs memory and regenerates every six hours, keeping record of the last key generated. For 10 seconds after the key changes, the server actually generates two HMACs; one with the new key, one with the old key. That way requests that are made while the key changed are still valid. If the key changed, the server sends the new one back to the client so its can flash it in LocalStorage. The key is a SHA256 of a UUID generated with node-uuid, hashed with crypto. And after typing this out, i realize this may not scale well, but anyway ...
3. The key is then stored in LocalStorage on the browser (the app actually spits out a your-browser-is-too-old page if LocalStorage is not supported before you can even try to login).
4. Then all requests beyond the initial authentication send three custom headers:

   - `Auth-Signature`: HMAC of `username`+`time`+`request.body` (in my case `request.body` is a `JSON.stringify()`'d representation of the request vars) signed with the locally stored key
   - `Auth-Username`: the `username`
   - `X-Microtime`: A unix timestamp of when the client generated its HMAC
5. The server then checks the `X-Microtime` header, and if the gap between `X-Microtime` and `now` is greater than 10 seconds, drop the request as a potential replay attack and throw back a 401.
6. Then the server generates is own HMAC using the same sequence as the client, `Auth-Username`+`X-Microtime`+`req.body` using the 6-hour private key in node memory.
7. If HMACs are identical, trust the request, if not, 401. And we have the `Auth-Username` header if we need to deal with anything user specific on the API.

All of this communication is intended to happen over HTTPS obviously.

## Edit:

The key would have to be returned to the client after each successful request to keep the client up to date with the dynamic key. This is problematic since it does the same thing that a cookie does basically.

You could make the key static and never changing, but that seems less secure because the key would never expire. You could also assign a key per user, that gets returned to the client on login, but then you still have to do user lookups on each request anyway, might as well just use basic auth at that point.

## Edit #2

So, after doing some testing of my own, i've decided to go with a backend proxy to my REST API still using HMAC.

1. Angular connects to same-domain backend, the backend runs the HMAC procedure from above, private key stored on this proxy. Having this on same domain allows us to block cors.
2. On successful auth, angular just gets a flag, and we store logged in state in LocalStorage. No keys, but something that identifies the user and is ok to be made public. For me, the presence of this stored value is what determines if the user is logged in. We remove the localStorage when they logout or we decide to invalidate their "session".
3. Subsequent calls from angular to same domain proxy contain user header. The proxy checks for user header (which can only be set by us because we've blocked cross-site access), returns 401 if not set, otherwise just forwards the request through to the API, but HMAC'd like above. API passes response back to proxy and thus back to angular.

This allows us to keep private bits out of the front end, while still allowing us to build an API that can authenticate quickly without DB calls on every request, and remain state-less. It also allows our API to serve other interfaces like a native mobile app. Mobile apps would just be bundled with the private key and run the HMAC sequence for each of their requests.

Comment: When you send back the universal private key are you also sending back a public key that identifies the user?

Comment: No, here i just use the Auth-Username header set in each request to the server. For me, since this is SSL, there's no difference in using a public key vs a plain text username. They are synonymous in my book. But i'm open to enlightenment there as well.

Comment: To clarify that comment, when the user logs in, we store their username in a User object, that then is used to build the Auth-Username header for the XHR request

Comment: @MattE, I've updated my answer with some new information. I'm not sure if this is the right way to use stack overflow, but thanks for lending an ear.

Comment: 1) What if I am a legitimate user, authenticate, get the key, and then  spoof someone else's username to keep generating HMAC requests? 2) What if I reverse engineer your mobile app to get the private key?

Comment: 1) You could create a public key for each user and store that. After authentication, you could return just that authenticated user's public key, making that part of the HMAC signing on both ends. That would cut down on trying to run requests as other non-authenticated users because you'd have to know other people's public key. Since we're SSL, there's really no way to get someone else's key unless you've authenticated as them to begin with (as far as I know). But, that would mean looking up the user's public key on the server for each request.

Comment: 2) for the web service, we have the proxy backend in our control to hide the private key auth, but for mobile, thats a great point, how can we secure that? I admit i'm still in research on this as well. I'd love to know how others are handing this too.

Comment: @marni, now that I'm thinking about it, we could technically support more than one authentication method in our REST service. OAuth, for example, isn't suited for javascript because you have to store private keys, but IS suited for mobile apps. So, why not use our HMAC setup w/ proxy'd backend for the angular interface, OAuth for mobile?